# mysql error code 1111. invalid use of group function. Why?

Tags: mysql

I want to know how many hours some student study, so that what I did:

```
select SUM( count(student.coursesID)*course.hours )
from course, student
where  

 student.courseID=course.courseID

AND student.studentID='086432467'
GROUP BY course.courseID;
```

However there was an error: `mysql error code 1111. invalid use of group function` Why? (Without sum it works good )

Comment: You can't nest COUNT function within the SUM function

Comment: the `SUM()` function is used on a list of integer. `count(student.coursesID)*course.hours` is one integer

Comment: How than such calculation can be done??

Comment: What calculation do you want to do?

Comment: "the SUM() function is used on a list of integer." Not completely true @Cid SUM () function also can take a SQL expression.. `SUM(column = 1)` for example is valid

Comment: @Cid To count how many hours some student study

Comment: @RaymondNijland what will be the result of that query?

Comment: it's better that you share example data on http://www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: `SUM(column = 1)` will only SUM where column's value is equal to 1 @Cid

Comment: `SELECT SUM(course.hours)` and everything left in your query should work

Comment: @RaymondNijland That's what I thought, and that's nice you can do that, it can really simplify some queries, thanks for the tip ! :-)

Comment: Can you please provide your tables with some examples